# How to do incremental load using TIMESTAMP?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a statement that does an incremental load from the database for a booking system (Sql) to the datawarehouse using an ELT tool (WhereEscape). What I'm trying to do is to write a where clause that checks wether the new record has a newer TIMESTAMP (A column created automatically when a booking is made) than the last recorded added to the warehouse.

I've used the following statements:

```
WHERE EV290_EXHIBITORS.EV290_ENT_STAMP > 
LOAD_EBMS_EV290_EXHIBITORS.EV290_ENT_STAMP
```

And:

```
WHERE EV290_EXHIBITORS.EV290_ENT_STAMP > (SELECT EV290_ENT_STAMP FROM LOAD_EBMS_EV290_ENT_STAMP)
```

Good to mention that all tools that are in use (the ELT tool and the warehouse) work using SQL Server syntax.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should handle this in your ETL solution.

Step 1: Query your destination table to get the latest timestamp.

Step 2: In your ETL package pass this value into your source stored procedure as a parameter

E.g.

```
WHERE EV290_EXHIBITORS.EV290_ENT_STAMP > @maxTimestamp
```

Step 3: Insert the data into your destination table.

I'd also advise taking your timestamp back a little while in order to overlap your loads (DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, @maxTimestamp) so that you're always reloading some data to ensure you catch anything that is late arriving. You will then need to either separate INSERT/UPDATE statements or  MERGE statement to insert your data.

Alternate Step 3: Load the resulting data into a work table in your destination database and then UPDATE/INSERT or MERGE into your destination table.

**EDIT**
However to directly answer your question, you need to change your query to:

```
WHERE EV290_EXHIBITORS.EV290_ENT_STAMP > (SELECT MAX(EV290_ENT_STAMP) FROM LOAD_EBMS_EV290_ENT_STAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

After initial load ETL should be incremental.

By design DWH system stores a wider range of data than OLTP systems do therefore not all the data is available on the OLTP system.

The secret is how to identify what has to be moved from OLTP to DWH staging tables, your row created/updated timestamp is a very valid and reliable strategy for extracting new data from OLTP system.

Comment: This is misleading. DWH don't store a wider range of data than OLTP systems. They might keep a longer history if you're archiving data from your OLTP system into your DWH, but OLTP systems can store the exact same data as your warehouse, just in a different architecture (optimised for smaller transactions).